# Index signature where key is string vs [string]

Tags: typescript, index-signature

What's the difference between these two?

```
let foo:{ [index:string] : string } = {
    ['hello']: 'world'
};

let bar:{ [index:string] : string } = {
    'hello': 'world'
};
```

I get the same result (`world`) when for the two values

```
console.log(foo['hello'])
console.log(bar['hello'])
```

Comment: As you're seeing, there's no difference. This is not TypeScript, even, it's a computed property name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015. For key values that are valid identifiers the quotes aren't needed either, `{ hello: "world" }` would work just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one allows to pass a variable between the square brackets:

```
const key = 'hello';

let foo:{ [index:string] : string } = {
    [key]: 'world'
};
```

But in your current example you're passing a plain string so you are using the dynamic syntax with a static key. `['hello']: 'world'` is fully equivalent to `'hello': 'world'`.